# Where to store p12 key for service account authentication in MVC app using Google Drive API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-drive-api, google-authentication

I'd like to create an MVC app in Visual Studio that connects to Google Drive via a service account.

Right now, I'm trying to understand the documentation and examples here:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#service_account

In that documentation, it gives an example for how to connect to the Google API using a service account credential (see the section titled "Service account".  The example creates a certificate object with this line:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

- Where is the "key.p12" file actually stored? (to be clear, I know how to download the file from google -- I'm asking where it goes in source control and on the server once I deploy).
- I'm using VisualStudio -- how should I have the key.p12 file deployed with the rest of the application when I publish?
- I assume the secret "notasecret" should be updated and secured. How do I update this secret and how do I pass it securely without hard coding it in my application?

Very new to this so please let me know if any of my questions don't make sense.

Thank you!